# How do i make my item function to be dependent on i.e user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

@item = Item.find(params[:id]), but this returns a value thats for all my logged on user, but i want it based on the id of the logged user

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding your question, so I apologize in advance if I am misinterpreting your question.

You are looking for a way to limit the search to only the items that belong to the currently logged in user?

This first requires an association between Item and User, something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then, assuming that you can access the currently logged in user using `current_user`, you can limit the search like so:

```
@item = current_user.items.find(params[:id])
```

Edit: If you have the user_id stored in the session as `session[:user_id]`, then you can do the following:

```
@user = User.find(session[:user_id])
@item = @user.items.find(params[:id])
```

Either way, the procedure is the same: start with a valid user object, and use the items relation to restrict the scope to items associated with that user.

Slightly off-topic, you may want to avoid storing the user_id directly in the session, as it can very easily be spoofed, allowing unwanted access (that would however, be a conversation for another question).

Comment: Thanks justin, that is what i want, but using the code u wrote gives this error 'undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<ItemsController:0x28b1b60>'

Comment: Can you post your ItemsController logic?  The solution depends on how your application handles authentication.  Most authentication methods provide the controller with a variable for the currently logged in user.  In the example I gave, this variable was "current_user", however it appears your application uses a different convention.

Comment: I'm trying to understand u, but the function for the user in my application i feel is session[:user_id] = user.id

Comment: Updated the answer based on storing the user ID in session[:user_id]